# AWK command to get value within a specified tag for list of XML files

Tags: xml, search, awk

I have a folder with 1000 XML files with the below tag present in all the XML files.

`<Employee_Name><![CDATA[ABC CORP]></<Employee_Name>`

Can you please help with me a UNIX command using AWK that will give me list of the unique values for the above tag mentioned. With the above example I will get only ABC CORP.

Comment: you need to give more details. Is that line present a single time in each file, or can there be more than 1 employee name's in a file?

Comment: 1 XML file has only 1 entry with "<Employee_Name><![CDATA[ABC CORP]></<Employee_Name>". All XML files has only 1 entry

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\["} {print $3;}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\]"} {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '<Employee_Name>' file| awk -F"><" '{print substr($2,2)}' | sort -u
```